# monacaで制作したアプリのiTunesConnectでのアプリ申請方法について教えてください

Tags: monaca, appstore-approval

monacaでアプリを作成し、テストビルドも無事に済んだのでいざアプリを配布するためにAppStoreへアプリを申請しようとしたところ、現在Appstoreの仕様が変わったため
monaca公式の
「App Store での配布
http://docs.monaca.mobi/3.5/ja/manual/deploy/appstore/reg_appstore/」
に記載の内容では、AppStoreへの申請が行えませんでした。

どうやらiTunesConnectを使うらしい…ということで、

iTunesConnectへログイン
↓
MyApps
↓
新規iOS App

の画面にて必要事項を入力したのですが、「作成」ボタンをクリックすると
「もう一度やり直してください。問題が解決しない場合はご連絡ください。」
というエラーが出てしまい、ここからまったく進めることができません。

自分なりに調べてみてApplicationLoaderもインストールしましたが、monacaを使った開発の場合でこのApplicationLoaderをどのように使うかも分からず、大変困っております。

どなたかmonacaを使った開発で、現行のアプリ申請のやり方をご教授いただけないでしょうか？
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 「問題が解決しない場合はご連絡ください。」とあるようですが、連絡はしてみましたか？そちらの方が明確な回答を得られる気がします。

Comment: citherさん
コメントありがとうございます。
AppStoreへの連絡は全文英語だったため心が折れていたのですが、
翌日改めて登録を試してみたところ、特に先日から登録内容に変更を加えたわけではないのですが何故かすんなりiTunesConnectでの作成が通りました。
原因は全く不明なのですが、なにはともあれiTunesConnectの件は解決致しました。
お騒がせして申し訳ありませんでした。そして助言くださりありがとうございました。引き続き申請作業を頑張ってみます。